# Why Mozilla FF does not update innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, mozilla, innerhtml

I'm trying to change the CSS of an HTML element dynamically...for that purpose i am using innerHTML.

The problem I'm facing is, maybe Mozilla remembers the innerHTML of a textarea on the first posting. So if the user edits the text in textarea, it fails to show new text and shows original text in textarea. In IE it works fine.

What's wrong with innerHTML and mozilla firefox ?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc()
{
    alert(document.getElementById("c").innerHTML);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="c" onclick="abc()">hello...</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: changing css through innerHTML How ????

Comment: I wonder how `<style>` tags inside input fields would parse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your requirement, why don't you just do:

```
document.getElementById("c").className = "myCSSClass";
```

because using `innerHTML` to change the CSS class of an element seems pretty weird...

Answer (score 4):

use .value for TextArea

Answer (score 1):

**cannot contain child elements, but value.**

Elements/value inside are treated as plain text not html.

You should use value property to retrieve its contents.

use:

```
document.getElementById('c').value
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use innerHTML?
The use of `innerHTML` is to dynamically insert the content to a specific tag using `id`.

you can use `alert(document.getElementById("c").value);`

Answer (score 0):

**Always use the `value` property to change the value of a `<textarea>`.**

It seems a common misconception that `innerHTML` is a viable or even superior way of doing this. It is neither.

What happens is that changing the `innerHTML` property of a text area will work only until the value has been changed, either by the user editing the contents of the textarea or by script changing the `value` property, because the child nodes of a textarea element represent only its **initial** value.

It's nothing to do with the standards-compliance or otherwise of `innerHTML`, or that only a single text node is legal within a `<textarea>` element: you get exactly the same behaviour if you try to change the `nodeValue` property of a text node contained within the `<textarea>` element.